# How to use WHERE in a one-to-many relationship without a subquery

Tags: sql

I want to retrieve all the records from A with all its relations in B when at least one of the codes in B matches a value.

Example A table

```
╔════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ GROUP║
╠════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ GP1  ║
║  2 ║ GP2  ║
║  3 ║ GP3  ║
╚════╩══════╩
```

Example B table

```
╔════╦══════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ A_ID         ║       CODE         ║
╠════╬══════════════╬════════════════════╣
║  1 ║           1  ║ COD1               ║
║  2 ║           1  ║ COD2               ║
║  3 ║           2  ║ COD3               ║
╚════╩══════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

Target result when `code=COD1`

```
╔════╦══════╦════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ GROUP║       CODE         ║
╠════╬══════╬════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ GP1  ║ COD1               ║
║  2 ║ GP1  ║ COD2               ║
╚════╩══════╩════════════════════╝
```

The query that I am using is this:

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id=B.a_id WHERE A.id = (SELECT a_id FROM B WHERE CODE ='COD1');
```

But I want to know if it's possible to get the same result without using the subquery.

I created this to test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97a7f9/5

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do?  And also tag with the database you are using.  And why do you want to avoid a subquery?

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "when `code=COD1`"? The expected result also contains a row with `code=COD2`

Comment: I have just updated the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your sample data, you can use:

```
select A.*, B.*
from A join
     B b1
     on A.id = b1.a_id AND b1.code = 'COD1' left join
     B
     on A.id = B.a_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4939d135ee1600a2c390b607bc286b18) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Very creative without subquery.  Nice

Answer (score 0):

```
 CREATE TABLE A
    (`id` int, `group` varchar(6))
 ;
    
 INSERT INTO A
    (`id`, `group`)
 VALUES
    (1, 'Group1'),
    (2, 'Group2'),
    (3, 'Group3')
 ;
 
 CREATE TABLE B
    (`id` int, `a_id` int, `code` varchar(4))
 ;
    
 INSERT INTO B
    (`Id`, `a_id`, `code`)
 VALUES
    (1, 1, 'COD1'),
    (2, 1, 'COD2'),
    (3, 2, 'COD3')
```

Query:

```
 SELECT A.*,B2.*
 FROM A INNER JOIN B B1
 ON A.ID=B1.A_ID 
 INNER JOIN B B2
 ON A.ID=B2.A_ID
 where B1.code='COD1'
```

Output:

| id | group | id | a_id | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Group1 | 1 | 1 | COD1 |
| 1 | Group1 | 2 | 1 | COD2 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=573d80e5f73449dcbe481c611a49a235)*

Comment: Their point was to NOT use a sub-query.  Using an EXISTS IS calling a subquery

Comment: Thanks @DRapp. You are right. I have updated my answer.